# Chrome Browser is causing Ubuntu 12.04 to crash

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, browser

Why does Chrome  browser cause Ubuntu 12.04 to crash. The keyboard & mouse cease to function and the screen displays lots of text which includes the word 'Panic'. This has never happened when Firefox was used (100's) but it's inevitable after an hour or so on Chrome.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when using Chromium browser?

Comment: The versions numbers won't not the same. The Chrome version is currently 21. I think the Chromium versions provided via Launchpad ppas or the Ubuntu Software Center are older. In other words, it's better to ask if this happened with earlier versions of Chrome with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).